# WPF: Relative Source to DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, binding, relativesource

If I have a data template as follows,

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:EditorTabViewModel}">
    <me:MarkdownEditor 
        TextContent="{Binding 
                          Path=Content, 
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:EditorTabViewModel}}}" ... />
</DataTemplate>
```

I wonder why Relative source can't find the `EditorTabViewModel`? Its just referring to the data template?

## UPDATE 1

The below works tho

```
<me:MarkdownEditor TextContent="{Binding Path=Content.Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />

Binding Path=Content.Content
                     ^ Refers to EditorTabViewModel.Content
             ^ refers to EditorTabViewModel
```

Is there a more ituitive markup? lol, i'd thought `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"` already refers to `EditorTabViewModel` at first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the `DataTemplate` is for objects of type `EditorTabViewModel`, its `DataContext` will already be a `EditorTabViewModel`. So you don't need to set a source at all:

```
TextContent="{Binding Content}" ... />
```

Comment: Hmm but if my `MarkdownEditor` is a UserControl that has `DataContext = this` I need to do that or else it will try to bind to a property of `MarkdownEditor` right?

Comment: Inside any DataTemplate the DataContext is always the data object the template is being applied to. When you have an explicitly specified DataType as in your example the DataContext will be an instance of that type.